# How to set a default `kind` and `priority` when creating a ticket in Bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket

When a new issue is created in bitbucket the default `kind` and `priority` are `bug` and `major` respectively.

[image]

How to change these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think they have anything like that. I was also looking for the same some time back but found this.

https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/2930/custom-issue-priorities.

As per current status it says

> We don't have custom issue priorities on the short term roadmap at the current time.

and status is

> on hold